# cannot instantiate abstract class c++

Tags: c++, class, abstract

I have a problem with this code - this is taskData:

```
static std::map<int8_t, std::vector<Task>> taskData;
```

and there is a problem:

```
taskData.emplace(pi::enumerations::taskManager::taskCategory_t::SECURITY, std::vector<Task>{FirefightingTask()});
```

FirefightingTask:

```
#pragma once

#include "Task.hpp"

namespace mc
{
    class FirefightingTask :public Task
    {
    public:

        FirefightingTask( uint8_t category = 0, uint8_t kind = 0, NPC* npc = nullptr );

        virtual bool act() override;
    };
}
```

Task:

```
#pragma once

#include "engine/Config.hpp" 

#include <queue>

class NPC;

namespace mc
{
    //Task
    //Represents a task for AI object
    class Task
    {

    public:
        Task(uint8_t category = 0, uint8_t kind = 0, NPC* npc = nullptr );

        uint8_t GetCategory()
        {
            return category;
        }

        uint8_t GetKind()
        {
            return kind;
        }

        bool operator==( const Task& second )
        {
            return this->kind == second.kind;
        }

        bool inProgress()
        {
            return doing;
        }

        virtual bool act() = 0;

    private:

        bool doing;

        const int8_t category;

        const int8_t kind;

        NPC* owner;
    };
}
```

and the error is:

> **Error   C2259   'mc::Task': cannot instantiate abstract class**

I really don't know why I get this error. When I remove this line:

```
        taskData.emplace(pi::enumerations::taskManager::taskCategory_t::SECURITY,std::vector<Task>{FirefightingTask()});
```

it works without problems :/

Comment: You need `std::vector<Task*>` or (better) `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>`.

Comment: Related read: [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: When i change it to shared_prt, there is the same problem taskData.emplace(pi::enumerations::taskManager::taskCateg‌​ory_t::SECURITY, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>>{std::make_shared<Task>(Fi‌​refightingTask())});

Answer (score 6):

The culprit is `std::vector<Task>` – you can't create a vector of `Task` since `Task` is abstract.

You need to use a vector of pointers.

Comment: When i change it to shared_prt, there is the same problem     taskData.emplace(pi::enumerations::taskManager::taskCategory_t::SECURITY, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>>{std::make_shared<Task>(FirefightingTask())});

Comment: @mvxxx YOu are using `make_shared` wrong. Right now you are trying to create `Task` object (abstract) from temporary `Fi‌​refightingTask`.

Comment: i have tried it:    taskData.emplace(pi::enumerations::taskManager::taskCategory_t::SECURITY, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>>{std::make_shared<FirefightingTask>(FirefightingTask())});
 and i got this error: 
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall mc::FirefightingTask::FirefightingTask(unsigned char,unsigned char,class mc::NPC *)" (??0FirefightingTask@mc@@QAE@EEPAVNPC@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl mc::TaskManager::loadData(void)" (?loadData@TaskManager@mc@@SAXXZ)

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is not allowed, as it would create objects of class "Task" which is abstract because of your "act" method.
Note that your solution from the other answer with std::make_shared won't work as well, since make_shared tries to create an instance of "Task".
You should try to create your firefightingTask with make_shared< FirefightingTask>().

An other note: you are using Task as virtual base class, so you should consider a virtual destructor.

Comment: when i try std::make_shared<FirefightingTask>... i have got external error

Answer (score 0):

`Task` is abstract, so there cannot be instances of it. A `std::vector` contains and owns instances of its value type. A `std::vector` of an abstract type is therefore impossible and doesn't make sense. You cannot contain and own something which cannot exist. That's the fundamental difference to vectors such as `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<FirefightingTask>`.

It doesn't help that the *dynamic* type of the objects inside of your vector is supposed to be something else (i.e. `FirefightingTask`). Only the static type is relevant for the compiler.

**Pointers**, however, can exist. They meet all conditions necessary to put them into a `std::vector`. What they point to is irrelevant for `std::vector`. The idea is that they statically point to `Task` and dynamically to `FirefightingTask` instances (or instances of other concrete subclasses).

Now, raw pointers should typically not be handled manually, because that's verbose and error-prone. Fortunately, C++ offers smart-pointer classes to prevent low-level memory-management mistakes. `std::unique_ptr` should be your default choice when it comes to smart pointers. Here is a simple example based loosely on your code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Task { virtual ~Task() = 0; };
struct FirefightingTask : Task {};
Task::~Task() {}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>> taskData;

    // map an empty vector of Task pointers to key 0:
    taskData.emplace(0, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>());

    // three times in a row, create a FirefightingTask instance
    // directly inside of the previously empty vector at key 0:
    taskData[0].emplace_back(std::make_unique<FirefightingTask>());
    taskData[0].emplace_back(std::make_unique<FirefightingTask>());
    taskData[0].emplace_back(std::make_unique<FirefightingTask>());
}
```

Comment: This make unresolved :/ 
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall mc::FirefightingTask::FirefightingTask(unsigned char,unsigned char,class mc::NPC *)" (??0FirefightingTask@mc@@QAE@EEPAVNPC@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Ref_count_obj<class mc::FirefightingTask>::_Ref_count_obj<class mc::FirefightingTask><>(void)" (??$?0$$V@?$_Ref_count_obj@VFirefightingTask@mc@@@std@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: @mvxxx: That's doubtful, because my code contains neither `NPC`, nor a `FirefightingTask` constructor with four parameters.

Comment: @mvxxx: `_Ref_count_obj` also sounds a lot like `std::shared_ptr`, not `std::unique_ptr`, because the former is reference-counted whereas the latter is not.

Comment: I know, i am using shared_ptr because i need it, but it does not solve my problem

Comment: @mvxxx: Why do you suddenly need `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Because i have got in NPC another vector which containts some elements of this vector:    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>> skills;

Comment: @mvxxx: It seems your new problem has nothing to do with the original question anymore.